# PROBLEM WITH COLLATION (NULL) CREATING A DATABASE SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Estoy creando una base de datos con el siguiente comando:

```
CREATE DATABASE CARGADOR COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO
```

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente comando:

```
select [Collation] = DatabasePropertyEx('CARGADOR','Collation')
```

El resultado es:

```
Collation
NULL
```

La pregunta es, ¿por qué `NULL`?

El resultado del siguiente comando:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('collation') SQLServerCollation
,DATABASEPROPERTYEX('master', 'Collation') AS MasterDBCollation

SQLServerCollation  MasterDBCollation
Modern_Spanish_CI_AS    Modern_Spanish_CI_AS

Y SELECT @@VERSION

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4458842) - 13.0.4224.16 (X64)   Aug 18 2018 09:00:06   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home Single Language 6.3 <X64> (Build 17134: )
```

Comment: He ejecutado los comandos tal cual los pones en tu pregunta y me trae la información sin ningún problema, ¿qué versión de SQL Server estás utilizando?